# What's the best way to store Keras model params and model architecture alongside of the model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'd like to save all the model parameters (optimizer, learning rate, batch size, etc.) and model architecture (number and types of layers) alongside of the model so that later go back analyze why some models works better.

**Is there a simple way to store this metadata along with the weights?**

Comment: I think if you are using tensorflow backend, `tf.train.Saver` can save optimizer and learning rate, I don't know whether it can save batch size but you can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model):

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

This includes the optimizer (which should include the learning rate and the batch size). Besides that, you can use

- Using configuration scripts which are under version control (I did so for my masters thesis, see [my configuration scripts](https://github.com/MartinThoma/msthesis-experiments/tree/master/experiments))
- Storing the training script

If you want one file, just use a container file format like `.tar`.